# Bootstrap Navbar-brand color change debug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
        color: #f0ad4e;
    }
```

And the following in my layouts/_header.html.erb that is being used in my layouts/application.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">....... etc..
```

How come my navbar brand won't change color! It's driving me crazy!

In my inspector I see the following:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
color: #999999;
}
```

So it's not taking effect, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue. This apprently did the trick:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #f0ad4e;
}
```

Comment: Did you add it into bootstrap.css?  Where?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the specificity of your selector to:

```
nav.navbar.navbar-inverse > div.navbar-header > a.navbar-brand {
    color: #f0ad4e;
}
```

The above may be overkill- so if it works, you should look to reduce it somewhat.

Comment: Shouldn't my original code work? I'ma a newb so maybe not, idk.

Comment: @user3597950 can you post a link to the site? This absolutely sounds like a specificity issue

Comment: What kinds of specificity can I give it?